# Using one GridView for everyNavigationItem

Tags: android

I have a Navigation Drawer in my App. The Navigation Drawer have 3 option (Button).
A **Grid View** will open with Img and Textview by clicking those option.
But now I want to use **only one Grid View** for those 3 option with 3 different Data Source.

How can i do it ?

**Child_GridView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ppr_img"
        android:layout_width="80.0dip"
        android:layout_height="80.0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/light_grey" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ppr_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**GridView_adapter.java**

```
public class CustomGridview extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] pprName;
    private final int[] pprImg;

    public CustomGridview(Context c, String[] channelname, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.pprImg = Imageid;
        this.pprName = channelname;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pprName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);

            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_grid, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ppr_name);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ppr_img);
            textView.setText(pprName[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(pprImg[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to use different data on the selection of the option of the NavDrawer on the same GridView?

Comment: Yes !! I want to use different data ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on the same Activity (Layout).

Initialise the variables (items to change data on different NavIten selection) on java.

Set a default value for your GridView (for default selection).

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.option1) {
        // set data on your GridView item

    } else if (id == R.id.option2) {
        // set data on your GridView item
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```